# MIPS : floating point

Tags: floating-point, mips, ieee-754, mips32

Let's say I have a float number 15.75 ... in $f0 register.

How can I cut the decimal part, and have the number 15?

I tried the below :

```
round.w.s $f0, $f0
mfc1 $a0, $f0            # moving the integer into $a0
li $v0, 1                # load code to print integer
syscall
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Didn't work _how_? Anyway, it sounds to me like you should be using the `floor` instruction rather than `round`.

Comment: Can you provide a url to the MIPS insttruction set?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use the `cvt.w.s` command, that directly converts a float number from a register into an integer which can be stored into another register.
An example would be:

```
.data

t: .asciiz "\n" 

n: .float 15.75

.globl main

.text

main:
#Convert fifteen into an integer

la $t1, n

l.s $f12, ($t1)             

cvt.w.s $f0, $f12           

li $v0, 2

syscall

la $a0, t

li $v0, 4

syscall

li $v0, 1

mfc1 $a0, $f0             

syscall

#Exit
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

This code will simply convert the number 15 as a float into an integer and print the results.